# How can I access my dropdownlist control within my DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datagrid

I have a DataGrid control (NOT GridView) that has 4 columns. One of the columns is a DropDownList. What I'm trying to do is access the DropDownList control from my dgTicket_ItemDataBound(.....) process and I'm having no success.

I've researched and tried several different ways with no success.

This is what I have:

```
protected void dgPrintTicket_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
      string SQL1 = @"SELECT Machine_Id FROM SFD00006 WHERE WC_Id = '" + wc + "'";

      DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlMachId");

      string val = ((DropDownList)dgPrintTicket.SelectedItem.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlMachId")).Text;

      if (ddl != null)
      {                    
          ddl.DataSource = Lib.getArrayList(SQL1);
          ddl.SelectedValue = val;
          ddl.DataBind();
      }
}
```

I want to access the DropDownList and populate it with all the Machine codes that I get from my select statement but my ddl keeps coming back as null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you all.

Sam

Comment: Just want to chime in that this is very unsafe code because it easily allows SQL injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive method of finding the control.

Here's how I would do it:

```
  Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string name) {
      if (root.Name == name) {
         return base;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < root.Controls.Count; ++i) {
           Control current = root.Controls[i];
           if (current.Name == name) {
               return current ;
           }
           else {
               Control recursiveControl = FindControlRecursive(current, name);
               if (recursiveControl != null)
               {
                    return recursiveControl;
               }
           }
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: this is a web app not a windows form

Comment: This logic should still apply, no?

Comment: Is this a procedure I'm calling and passing a variable to? I'm not sure I understand what this is doing? What do the parameters 'root' and 'name' represet?